# NMI watchdog on Haswell

Tags: boot, cpu, watchdog

When i'm trying to boot ubuntu on my laptop (Asus Transformer Book Trio TX201L), i'm getting this

```
[ 60.079064] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s! [swapper/0:0]
```

The only way i can boot now is to load Windows, set the perfomance power plan and then Ubuntu boots normally. I believe, the problem is that CPU's frequency is too low on start. Is there any way to solve this problem?

P.S. CPU - Intel haswell 4200u, intel p-state is installed

---

The problem was solved by installing new kernel (4.5)

Comment: That is a very interesting workaround. Which version of Ubuntu? It might help if you would post your `/var/log/kern.log` file (including both a successful boot and and unsuccessful boot) to a [paste site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and adding the link to your question. If your are running thermald, try disabling it, just for a test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply) I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 (kernel - 4.2.0-25-generic)

Comment: This is log of normal boot (after Windows) [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14681246/)

Comment: And this is log of "cold" boot [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14681393/)

Comment: I see that you actually have problems with both ways of booting, it is just that one way seems to somewhat recover. Do you know how to disable thermald? Or even determine if you have it? It would also be good to disable the microcode update, again just as a test. Is this a new problem as of kernel 4.2.0-25-generic or did it also occur with the previous kernel, presumably 4.2.0-24-generic?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I fixed that problem by moving to a new kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing new kernel (4.5)